# What is a dirty resource?

Tags: ruby, datamapper

I just started using Datamapper.

I am trying to `update` an object. I get the object/model using its id:

```
u1 = User.get(1)
u1.name = "xyz" 
u1.update
```

which throws a error/raises an exception. I tried again:

```
u1 = User.get(1)
```

and after that:

```
u1.update({:name => "xyz"})
```

will throw false and `dirty?` returns `true`.

After that any call to `update` would fail saying it is dirty.

I can do a save by:

```
u1.name = "xyz"
u1.save
```

Here are my questions:

- What should I be using: Save or update?
- Should I say `get(id)` even to just change one field?
- When should I use `update`? What is the syntax: `user.update({ ....})` or `user.name = "xyz"; user.update`?
- What is `dirty?`, and is it once I make a object dirty do I have to
  get the object fresh from the database to the variable?

Comment: Oh, "What is a dirty resource" could go so wrong.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you fetched a resource from the db and then changed its attributes then the resource becomes 'dirty'. This means that the resource is loaded into memory and its state has changed and changes can be persisted in the db.

You use `#save` to persist changes made to a loaded resource and you use `#update` when you want to immediately persist changes without changing resource's state to 'dirty'. Here's an example session:

```
User.create(:name => 'Ted')

# update user via #save
user = User.get(1)
user.name = 'John'
user.dirty? # => true
user.save

# update user via #update
user = User.get(1)
user.update(:name => 'John')
user.dirty? # => false
```